# persistent local variable in c

Tags: c, variables, persistent

Are persistent variables not widely used?  I couldn't find much info about them online or in the index of my C textbook - the Art and Science of C.

Anything you can share about them, especially their **scope and example declaration** would be helpful.   I'm guessing to declare them you use 'persistent' as the keyword?

```
static void foo( void ) {
  persistent unsigned int width = 5;
}
```

This is the only other helpful reference I could find:
“Persistent variables keep their state when the board is turned off and on, when main is run, and when system reset occurs. Persistent variables will lose their state when code is downloaded as a result of loading or unloading a file.”
http://www.newtonlabs.com/ic/ic_5.html#SEC9

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword you want is `static` in local (not global) context.

The context thing is important:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int foo;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  //...
}
```

Here `static` means that `foo` has file scope (i.e. is not `extern`).

Whereas in

```
char *strtok(char *str, char *sep){
  static char *last;
  //...
}
```

`last` is persistent between calls to `strtok`.

All that said, they are rarely used because they are rarely useful, and are totally unacceptable in a multi-threaded context (where they are a race condition waiting to happen).

Comment: wow, coming back to this thread when i took my first class.  i didn't know what was meant by 'persistent'.  thanks again all

Comment: This answer somewhat misses the mark.  The `static` keyword has to do with variable scope, and is part of the C standard.  The `persistent` keyword controls how the variable memory is initialized at startup, and is not standard C.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357304/973624 for a more complete answer.

Comment: @mrtumnus Uhhh ... yeah. I ought to delete it, but while it is accepted I can't do that. I have to wonder why tarabyte accepted it.

Answer (score 8):

Interactive C (the link you provided) provides the `persistent` keyword, but that **is not standard C**. Particularly since guarantees like "*keep their state when the board is turned off and on, when main is run, and when system reset occurs*".

`persistent` is provided with the Interactive C compiler and works with dedicated hardware, Motorola chip in this case, storing the variable value in non-volatile memory to achieve persistence over restarts.

> Interactive C is a C compilation environment for many Motorola 6811 based robots and embedded systems. Originally developed for the MIT LEGO Robot Design Contest (6.270), Interactive C has enjoyed widespread distribution and use. Interactive C's claim to fame is its interactivity: users can type in expressions and have them compiled on the fly and run immediately, rather than waiting for lengthy compile and download cycles. IC currently supports the 6.270, the HandyBoard and the RugWarrior and RugWarrior Pro.
>   [source](http://www.newtonlabs.com/ic/).

To achieve variable persistence in a local scope (e.g. function), use the `static` keyword.

Comment: `persistent` is also a keyword in Microchip's 8-bit compiler. It likewise indicates that the specified variable should not be cleared by the runtime startup code.

Answer (score 2):

As jkerian mentioned, persistent variables keep their state when the board is turned off and on ... but are excluded by the C startup code (which is compiler dependent) because the only memory that can be used for this, is the EEPROM.

Like other variables, persistent variables stored in volatile memory lose content on a power lost. But this kind of variable is useful on device with FRAM. FRAM is an acronym for ferroelectric RAM whitch is a non-volatile memory that can hold data even after it is powered off.
Note: on CCS in COFF mode, uninitialized variables weren't set to 0 (to save startup time) and therefore were always persistent.

Answer (score 1):

I often use Persistent variables in my PIC MCU software. For instance, I would define an integer array for holding error codes, that I would want to retain after a reset (whether hardware, instruction, watchdog etc.). In addition I would define an integer variable for checking the integrity of all the persistent data. When the program starts I would compare the contents of the check variable with a particular value. This could be any pre-defined value, but I would choose something that the ram is unlikely to power-up with, such as 0xA5F0. If the check variable contains this value, then I can assume all the other persistent variables have retained their data, and move on. However, if the check variable does not compare with 0xA5F0, then I assume all the other persistent variables contain invalid data, so I would initialise them all, and set the check variable to 0xA5F0.